# What does "the poet" do?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

From time to time I read quotes that are described post-quote using a word that further describes or amplifies what the person did. Further, that word often follows an action that helps to define the person and the action (to avoid arguments about the accuracy of who-does-what I have excluded examples).

So, my question is this: how is a poet described when they do what they do? I am not asking for an opinion because I can fill in a word; I'd like to know, how does one describe the act or process of writing poetry?  My initial thoughts are that she might "muse" which is close but that term is already taken by philosophers; he might "theorize" but that's too scientific; and while a poet definitely writes their words, you generally will not write, "the poet wrote" and expect that to convey the full meaning.

Alternately, a potential fill-in the blank that matches what I am attempting to write: `"'Two roads diverged,'" the poet _____(ed)."`

I'll continue to adjust the question as commentary suggests.

Comment: A poet can do many things. Write, opine, rhyme, compose, so it's my leaning to vote to  close this question as too broad and/or opinion based.

Comment: I'm not understanding what's wrong with 'quoth' itself for this purpose. It's typically used to provide an archaic or humorous flavor, which would fit with your stated goal.

Comment: Clare: it is broad and you are correct that a poet can do many things ("suffer" was suggested by a friend of mine); I'll update to make it a bit more specific.

Comment: The poet notices.

Comment: Poets are writers. They do what other writers do, and 100+ verbs can go in that blank.

Comment: And if you want to be sure folks see your comments use @ before their username. You don't have to do this when you are addressing the author of a question or answer post.

Comment: "Quoth" does not mean quoted or restated. It simply means "said".

Comment: Poets write poesy, but poesyed never seems to have made it into the English language: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/poesy

Comment: This is completely opinion based. It is your opinion that "instructed" suggests a teacher, "opined" suggests a lawyer, or "summarized" suggests a lawyer. I don't recognise any of these words as pertaining to a specific profession.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your assumption about the speakers being teachers, writers or lawyers. Even if you choose to make those inferences, that does not mean that whoever wrote the sentence actually implied it.

Comment: @AndyT & atFlater - I see what you are saying but I am not "stating" that the author has a profession, I am "suggesting" that one is implied and recognize that a broader context might be required to convey that suggestion. To that end, I'm not asking for opinions, I'm asking if anyone has a specific word.  If one doesn't exist, then I"ll close.

Comment: Sorry, SammyB; your premise stands on thin ice, right from *quoth* means *spoke*, not *quoted.*

Can you justify those *suggesting a…*? They don’t.

In your book, what’s the difference between *the best…* and *most-appropriate…*?

A poet *musing* would be to deny the nature of poetry.

Poets don’t *theorize*; they state what they feel is true.

Who knows what *”the poet waxed" sounds like she's getting ready for a half-pipe run* means?

Of course poets *write*; it’s their job.

*Leaves are falling all around*, the poet said/wrote/declared/stated/concluded/(100 synonyms)…

Comment: Very broadly, poets use *writing* as a medium to *explain* the way the world is… and necessarily, almost any attempt to *analyse* poetry will fail.

See, for instance *The Dead Poets' Society* and particularly, the tearing out of *analytical* pages…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - FYI (and partly based on SammyB's comment on an answer) - a snowboarder will rub wax on their board in order to reduce the friction between the board and the snow/ice of a half-pipe; unsurprisingly the verb for this is "to wax". I can only assume that SammyB's life experiences mean that "to wax" has predominantly this meaning for him.

Comment: Andy, please remember the dangers of assumption.

*To wax*, as in snowboarding and *to wax poetic*, as in literature, have nothing whatever in common.

Whatever you assume, your idea of *to wax* as in boarding is pretty-much perfect.

Whatever you didn't bother to research, *to wax* as in *to wax poetic* is completely different. Broadly, *to wax* in that sense means *to grow*, just as its opposite *to wane* means broadly to *shrink* or *diminish*… as most recognized in https://www.hymnal.net/en/hymn/h/145

Comment: The poet lied.  The poet shouted.  The poet muttered.  The poet scrawled.  The poet refuted.  The poet railed.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=written+a+poem%2Ccomposed+a+poem%2C+created+a+poem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwritten%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomposed%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccreated%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Clare: Dad joke of they day: What does a _bad_ poet do? They poetaster. Look man, you have to take the opportunity when you can.

Answer (score 1):

*compose*?
*scrawl*?
*Wax* may be the most poetry-specific, as in *wax poetic* or *wax lyrical*.

Comment: "...the poet waxed." hmmm...sounds more like something a snowboarder would do :)

Comment: It is possible that some people misanalyse those expressions to take that meaning for _wax_, but its general meaning is "grow" (as in "wax and wane"). So those mean "grow (or 'become') poetic/lyrical".

Answer (score 0):

Some writers use words of this kind in order to avoid using 'he said' all the time, while others prefer just to stick with 'said'. 'He instructed' could be used of anyone giving directions to another person; it doesn't imply that they are a professional 'instructor'. So you can use any verb you like for your poet.